# Double-sided exponential distribution - Lindeberg's condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

If double-sided exponential distribution has density $$
g(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda|x|}
$$ and we have a sequence of independent r.v.s $X_n$ where each of them has double-sided exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, prove that there exist sequences $a_n, b_n$ such that
$$
\frac{\left(\sum_\limits{1\leq k \leq n}X_k\right)-a_n}{b_n} \text { converges weakly to } N(0,1)
$$

I know this is a Lindeberg's CLT type of task but I was unable to proceed any further than finding out that $\mathbb{E}X^2 = \frac{2}{\lambda^2}$ and$\mathbb{E}X = \frac{2}{\lambda}$. If we took $X_n$s with $\lambda=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ that would make $\sum \mathbb{E} X_n \sim cn$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sum \mathbb{E} X_n^2 \sim d n^3$ for some $d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Could anyone solve this example? I tried looking for similar example but there aren't many examples of such CLT on math.stackexchange.

Comment: what do you mean you were unable to proceed further? did you or did you not find numbers $\mu_n$ in the Lindeberg's condition? I would write an answer but seeing as you did some work, I would prefer to give series of smaller hints.

Comment: Why don't you answer to the question of @dezdichado ? This site is based on dialog...